# What's the most appropriate way to load Mapbox Studio tiles in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-studio

I'm updating a Leaflet map's basemap, and I'd like to use Mapbox to create this basemap. At first I thought I would have to ditch Leaflet and switch entirely to Mapbox GL. After digging around in the Mapbox API documentation I found [an endpoint for requesting raster tiles from Mapbox Studio styles](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/styles/#Request.tiles.from.a.style) and I got this working in Leaflet.

Is there a problem with loading the tiles this way? Can I expect this method to work for the foreseeable future despite the emphasis Mapbox has been putting on vector tiles? It seems like my only other option is [mapbox-gl-leaflet](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet), which is experimental.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The endpoint for Studio-made styles is available and stable for use with Leaflet.

```
        var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

    L.tileLayer(
'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/emerald-v8/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=<your token>', {
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/map-feedback/">Mapbox</a> © <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(mymap);
```

Note your tiles will have a zoomOffset that needs to be adjusted for. Also,  be sure to use your Style with a token that has the scope `styles:tiles` enabled. You can always use Mapbox.js which includes Leaflet as well. Reference: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-studio-style/

Comment: Did this work for you? I'm getting all blank tiles.

Comment: I found setting option `maxNativeZoom: 22` is needed so if you zoom in past Mapbox's supported zoom level, leaflet shows a scaled version of supported tiles [(docs)](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#gridlayer-option:~:text=maxNativeZoom)  
 -- at least for `outdoors-v11`

Answer (score 5):

Geografa's answer is referring to tiles made with "Mapbox Studio Classic" (which was originally named "Mapbox Studio"). These "Classic" styles are found on your Mapbox account at https://www.mapbox.com/studio/classic/

*(According to mapbox's documentation, [the url structure for retrieving the raster tiles had changed](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-raster-tiles-from-styles) since geografa's answer but I received 404 errors loading my "classic" tiles using Mapbox's update URL structure).*

As of December 2018, 
If you're looking to use tiles that were built with Mapbox Studio within Leaflet:

1. Go to the list of Styles in Studio (current url is https://www.mapbox.com/studio/)
2. click on the 'share & use' button for style you wish to use
3. click on the use tab in the new pop-up that appeared
4. select "third-party" on left-hand side of menu
5. select "Carto" in the new pop-up

Your screen should look like this: [image: Go to styles in studio, share & use button, use, third party, carto]"Mapbox Studio"

This "integration URL" is your [urltemplate](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#tilelayer) and can be used in leaflet within the L.tileLayer like in [this basic leaflet example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/).

Comment: thanks, trying this now and I'm getting 404s, is this still working?

Answer (score 2):

Mapbox has made this less obvious, see the updated image below.

1. On your Mapbox Studio **Styles** page
2. Click the "Share your style" button:

[image]

3. A popup will appear:

[image]

3. In the lower section of the popup, select the **Third party** tab.
4. There’s a drop-down menu likely displaying **WMTS**, select **CARTO**.
5. Copy the "Integration URL" link provided. It should have the "{z}/{x}/{y}" part in the URL.

Comment: Is there any way to do this programmatically, if you have hundreds of tiles, adding them to studio and then getting the link for each doesn’t make sense. Is there no end point to directly access the tile set without going through studio?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'd recommend posting this as a new question.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366018/programmatic-way-of-accessing-mapbox-tileset-from-leaflet-without-studio