# Leaflet with Mapbox tile layer

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I have created a Mapbox custom style map and want to use it in Leaflet. All the examples on this site and the web refer to a map ID that doesn't seem to be used anymore.

For example:

```
https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}
```

Mapbox seems to currently only provide a "Leaflet URL". 
For example:

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/myusername/cj7v3234324/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiYWltZWVfvevervCIsImEiOiJjajdrvevrjQwNGx4MndudjVqbGd1ZG1xIn0.5j60jT7XVIkSKpw7vdvsdJXA
```

This URL includes what looks like a style reference and an access token but no .png.

I cannot make this work in any way with Leaflet `L.tilelayer`. I have tried various ways of editing the URL.

Comment: Duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182442/whats-the-most-appropriate-way-to-load-mapbox-studio-tiles-in-leaflet ?