# Programmatic way of accessing mapbox tileset from leaflet WITHOUT studio

Tags: r, leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-studio, shiny

I have a R shiny app that successfully uses leaflet to interact with a custom mapbox studio style.

```
mapbox_url = "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/bweinstein/ck94nmzn20an31imrz6ffplun/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=####"
leaflet() %>% addTiles(mapbox_url)
```

To do this I

1. Uploaded tileset to mapbox
2. Created a new style and added the tileset as a source
3. Click share in studio and got the CARTO link (as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34072237/how-can-i-use-a-custom-created-mapbox-style-along-with-leaflet)

Is there anyway to programmatically create styles, or better yet, directly get the tileset without studio? Studio styles have a limit of 15 sources. I have hundreds of tiles that I'd like to programmatically choose in my app.

### Expected behavior

If I have a tileset with the id

```
bweinstein.CypressCity_03_25_2020
```

I expected the tileset to be available at url:

```
mapbox_url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/bweinstein/bweinstein.CypressCity_03_25_2020/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=####'
```

I've tried a number of variants, e.g.

```
mapbox_url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/bweinstein/CypressCity_03_25_2020/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=####'
```

I don't see anything here: https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/overview/publish-your-style/#leaflet but this seems like a core use-case?

## Edit

The answer [Using Mapbox tiles with folium](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203062/using-mapbox-tiles-with-folium) from 2016 uses classic mapbox API and appears deprecated.

```
MacBook-Pro:Downloads ben$ curl http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/bweinstein.CypressCity_03_25_2020/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=#####
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: s.tiles.mapbox.com
```

Current tileset API cannot find it

```
MacBook-Pro:Downloads ben$ curl http://api.mapbox.com/v4/bweinstein.CypressCity_03_25_2020/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=######
{"message":"Not Found"}
```

Comment: getting closer here: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#example-request-body-create-a-style

Comment: sounds like you may be better off hosting your tiles with maptiler which allows a certain number (I dont know how much) to be hosted in their cloud for free. https://cloud.maptiler.com/

Comment: You might find your answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/203062/using-mapbox-tiles-with-folium. It seems that your tileset is identified by `userId.tilesetId` combination..

Comment: @TomazicM that first answer is from five years ago and seems to apply only to deprecated "mapbox classic" tiles? I'm struggling to understand why such a critical use-case was deprecated?

Comment: According to docs at https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#raster-tiles syntax `https://tiles.mapbox.com/v4/userId.tilesetId/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` should work, but I couldn't get it working either.

Comment: I contacted mapbox support and directed them here. @TomazicM when you test, are you trying from curl? I added an example just to document.

Comment: No, I'm using IIS + HTML + JS + Leaflet. When I tried with style, it worked OK.

Comment: agreed. Thanks for responding. I currently do not see anyway to serve individual tilesets, this feels unlikely. Waiting for support.

Comment: New finding. At my first attempt I mistakenly used grid url template for my test vector layer. So, for vector layers it's working with this template: `https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{layerId}/{z}/{x}/{y}.vector.pbf?access_token={token}`. For raster layer it should then be `https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{layerId}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={token}`, where `layerId` is combination `userId.tilesetId`.

Comment: Your `curl` attempt didn't work because you didn't replace parameters `{x}`, `{y}` and `{z}` with some actual values.

Comment: yes, sorry, that's true if you go look up the slippy mapname, query the file, etc, but it doesn't answer how to connect a tileserver service to leaflet, right? If i'm wrong, definitely offer an answer below, i'd like to see.

Comment: I'm not familiar with R and Shiny, but this link might help you in the right direction: https://www.r-bloggers.com/adding-basemap-at-tiles-to-an-r-leaflet-plot/

Comment: You could try out the new mapboxapi R package: https://github.com/walkerke/mapboxapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple. Don't construct the URL yourself.

```
  leaflet() %>% addProviderTiles("MapBox", 
                   options = providerTileOptions(id = "bweinstein.CypressCity_03_25_2020",
                                                 accessToken ="########"))
```